# Correct way to use FieldValue.serverTimestamp() in Typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-admin

Using Tyepscript, I'm trying to set the `createdAt` field in one of my Firebase functions with `FieldValue.serverTimestamp()` but I'm always getting the following error:

> Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'serverTimestamp'){"severity":"WARNING","message":"Function returned undefined, expected Promise or value"}

What datatype should I be using for this to work? In my code below I created a **Category** interface.

```js
import * as functions from "firebase-functions";
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';
import {firestore} from "firebase-admin";
import FieldValue = firestore.FieldValue;


interface Category {
  name: string;
  uid: string;
  createdAt: FieldValue;
}

export const createUser = functions.auth.user().onCreate((user) => {
  const db = admin.firestore()
  const ref = db.collection(`users/${user.uid}/category`).doc()

  try {
    const category: Category = {
      name: `test`,
      uid: user.uid,
      createdAt: FieldValue.serverTimestamp()
    }
    ref.set(category)
  }
  catch(e) {
    console.log((e as Error).message)
  }
})
```

Comment: I completely forget that functions run on the server so I've resorted to using `new Date()` to get the current date instead. Is this the correct way or is there a "firebase" way of getting the timestamp?

Comment: It looks like the issue might be that the FieldValue object is being imported as a type instead of a value. Try changing this line:


```
import {firestore} from "firebase-admin";
```


to this:


```
import * as firestore from "firebase-admin";
```


This should allow you to use FieldValue.serverTimestamp() as a value rather than a type.

Comment: Still the same. I updated the interface so `createdAt` would have a type of `admin.firestore.FieldValue;` then tried getting the date with `admin.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()`.

Comment: Are you using `>v11.0.0` by chance? Also see the [API reference](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/FieldValue.html#.serverTimestamp)

Comment: `firebase --version` is `11.19.0`

Comment: @enchance my answer below should work in that case. Were you able to try it out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firebase Admin SDK uses a modular syntax like client SDKs to some extent from `v10`. Try refactoring the code as shown below:

```
import * as functions from "firebase-functions";
import { initializeApp } from "firebase-admin/app";
import { FieldValue, getFirestore } from "firebase-admin/firestore";

initializeApp();

const db = getFirestore()
const serverTimestamp = FieldValue.serverTimestamp();

export const createUser = functions.auth.user().onCreate(async (user) => {
  const ref = db.collection(`users/${user.uid}/category`).doc()
  
  try {
    const category: Category = {
      name: `test`,
      uid: user.uid,
      createdAt: FieldValue.serverTimestamp()
    }
    await ref.set(category;
  } catch (e) {
    console.log((e as Error).message)
    return;
  }
})
```